# Convert datatable to JSON then post it to Jquery method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar

I'm working in ASP.Net and c#.  I have a DataTable that I converted to a JSON string (on the .aspx.cs side of the web page) and I need to send this JSON to a Jquery method (on the .aspx side).

Specifically, I'm trying to use the FullCalendar.js to display a schedule of classes for students.  I fetch all the information for the schedules and store it in the DataTable.  Then convert to JSON.

How I can I post this to the html page?  What js do I use to capture the right JSON? Is there a better way to do this and I'm going down the wrong road entirely? I'm unfamiliar with Jquery and pretty lost.  Any help appreciated.

HTML code here, Test.aspx

```
 <div id="calendar"></div>
                        
    <script>
        // The calendar needs to load the schedule data from a JSON string
        // Code here to find and use the JSON coming from Test.aspx.cs
        var calendar = new Calendar(calendar, {
            });
    </script>
```

c# code here Test.aspx.cs

```
protected string ConvertDataTabletoString(int studentId)
{
    // Fetch the class schedule from the database
    DataTable tblClasses = ClassAccess.GetClassesByStudentId(studentId);
    // Serialize
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row;
    foreach (DataRow dr in tblClasses.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in tblClasses.Columns)
        {
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }
    // Put into string
    string jsonToBeSent = serializer.Serialize(rows);

    // Now send to HTML side of the page to be captured by Jquery method
    // ??????????????????????
}
```

Comment: Please do read on networking, How this works is you setup up a server in back end and with the front end you  make a request to that server , you can so that in jquery with ```$.ajax()``` method

Comment: `return jsonToBeSent;` . But you probably need to make ConvertDataTabletoString into a WebMethod so that you can have a URL to it, and fullCalendar can request that URL - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed . Make sure the table data is in the format required by fullCalendar. A raw DataTable might not do that, so you perhaps would be better with a strongly typed object, or even anonymous types, if you're building on the fly. Also JSON.NET is a far better serializer than the old JavaScriptSerializer. It handles dates properly, for one thing.